# Extracting parts of data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an issue while extracting and creating a new data.frame on the basis of previous one.

So we have:

```
 > head(data.raw)
        date id      contacted    contacted_again region
1 2015-11-29 234            CHAT           EMAIL   APAC
2 2015-11-29 234           EMAIL           EMAIL   APAC
3 2015-11-27 257           PHONE           PHONE   EMEA
4 2015-11-27 278           PHONE           EMAIL   APAC
5 2015-11-27 293            CHAT           EMAIL   EMEA
6 2015-11-27 243           EMAIL           EMAIL   EMEA
             market                                          
1             AU/NZ
2 SE Asia (English)
3             Spain
4    China Mainland
5              DACH
6              DACH
```

However, one I write

```
data.ru <- data.raw[data.raw$market=="Russia",]
```

I receive the following mess:

```
           date             id      contacted    contacted_again region market
67   2015-11-25            334             CHAT           EMAIL   EMEA Russia
NA         <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
NA.1       <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
NA.2       <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
NA.3       <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
NA.4       <NA>            <NA>            <NA>            <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
```

How should I write a command to receive just a normal data.frame with all rows that $market=="Russia" without any NAs?

Comment: You probably have `NA`s in your data and R doesn't know how to handle them so it just leaves them there. you can easily recreate this using `x <- c(1, 2, 1, 1, NA, NA) ; x[x == 1]` for instance. In this case this could be solved using `x[x == 1 & !is.na(x)]`. Also, please don't forget to add the language tag next time too.

Comment: Observation numbers don't have NAs (ie. 1,2,3 etc.) but in this case even them receive NAs. Also, not a single observation with [=="Russia"] statements has all NAs in itself.

Comment: What does `sum(is.na(data.raw$market))` gives you?

Comment: Oh thanks! Adding !is.na(data.raw$market) really helped but can you explain the logic behind it? I mean according to summary() there are no NAs in the $market vector - but will I still receive observations where at least one of other rows has NA? And why then it returns NAs when $market vector is complete? Thanks!

Comment: When I do `x <- c(1, 2, 1, 1, NA, NA) ; summary(x)` it does tell me I have `NA`s, so not sure  what you mean. Also if `sum(is.na(data.raw$market))` is not zero, then it's not complete.

Comment: Moreover, even though there might be NAs (actually according to `sum(is.na(data.raw$market))` there are none) why do I still receive rows with them if I specified those only meeting $market requirement? According to the same logic _NA != "Russia"_, nope?

Comment: R doesn't know what `NA`s is by definition. Thus it doesn't know if it meets the `== "Russia"` condition or not. Thus, by default it displays it too just in case.

Comment: Oh, I see now - it's all clear then! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just use the subset function.

```
test <- data.frame(x = c("USA", "USA", "USA", "Russia", "Russia", NA), y = c("Orlando", "Boston", "Memphis", NA, "St. Petersburg", "Mexico City"))
print(test)
      x              y
1    USA        Orlando
2    USA         Boston
3    USA        Memphis
4 Russia           <NA>
5 Russia St. Petersburg
6   <NA>    Mexico City

subset(test, x == "Russia")
       x              y
4 Russia           <NA>
5 Russia St. Petersburg
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try: data.ru <- data.raw[data.raw$market %in% "Russia",]

Explanation: I am assuming you have empty lines in your dataset, which are read as NAs (missing value). Since R cannot know if a given NA is equal to "Russia" or not, the generated data frame includes them.

Illustration in code:

```
# create sample dataset
example.df <- data.frame(market=c(NA, "Russia", NA), outcome = c(1,2,3)) 

# match market using ==
example.df$market == "Russia"
example.df[example.df$market == "Russia",]

# match market using %in%
example.df$market %in% "Russia"
example.df[example.df$market %in% "Russia",]
```